# Revoke in Redshift not removing access to schema

Tags: permissions, amazon-redshift, sql-revoke

I am trying to remove a user's permissions to multiple schemas to which they had previously been granted access via security groups. However, using the revoke command is not working to do that.

User, KYKE, had been granted access to a number of schemas via a security group.

Removed user from group.... alter group BAMKT drop user KYKE. My DB client will generate the SQL to build each security group and when I do so I can confirm that user, KYKE, is no longer associated with group BAMKT.

However, when I run this sql..
SELECT distinct derived_table1.schemaname,
--derived_table1.objectname,
derived_table1.usename username,
'USER' usertype
,
derived_table1.select_flag,
derived_table1.insert_flag,
derived_table1.update_flag,
derived_table1.delete_flag,
derived_table1.reference_flag
FROM ( SELECT objs.schemaname, objs.objectname, usrs.usename,
CASE
WHEN has_table_privilege(usrs.usename, objs.fullobj::text, 'select'::text) THEN 1
ELSE 0
END AS select_flag,
CASE
WHEN has_table_privilege(usrs.usename, objs.fullobj::text, 'insert'::text) THEN 1
ELSE 0
END AS insert_flag,
CASE
WHEN has_table_privilege(usrs.usename, objs.fullobj::text, 'update'::text) THEN 1
ELSE 0
END AS update_flag,
CASE
WHEN has_table_privilege(usrs.usename, objs.fullobj::text, 'delete'::text) THEN 1
ELSE 0
END AS delete_flag,
CASE
WHEN has_table_privilege(usrs.usename, objs.fullobj::text, 'references'::text) THEN 1
ELSE 0
END AS reference_flag
FROM ( SELECT pg_tables.schemaname, 't'::character varying AS obj_type, pg_tables.tablename AS objectname, (pg_tables.schemaname::text + '.'::text + pg_tables.tablename::text)::character varying AS fullobj
FROM pg_tables
UNION
SELECT pg_views.schemaname, 'v'::character varying AS obj_type, pg_views.viewname AS objectname, (pg_views.schemaname::text + '.'::text + pg_views.viewname::text)::character varying AS fullobj
FROM pg_views) objs,
(
SELECT pg_user.usename
FROM pg_user
where usename = 'KYKE'
) usrs
ORDER BY objs.fullobj) derived_table1
WHERE (derived_table1.select_flag + derived_table1.insert_flag + derived_table1.update_flag + derived_table1.delete_flag + derived_table1.reference_flag) > 0
and schemaname not in ('information_schema','pg_catalog', 'pg_automv')

...full code shorted for breviety.

The user KYKE still has access to a number of schemas to which he previously had been granted access via the BAMKT security group.

So then I attempt to remove access to each schema using the following commands:
revoke all privileges on all tables in schema BAMKT from KYKE
revoke usage on schema BAMKT from KYKE

Commands complete without failure but still user KYKE continues to have access to schema BAMKT

I want to remove all the users permissions so that if the account owns some object and/or is used in a Tableau report, I can recreate permissions without also recreating the account and password.

So what am I doing wrong? Why can't I remove KYKE's access to any schemas?

Comment: To confirm, you're assuming the user has access based on the query you're running above? What happens when you revoke usage and revoke all, and then impersonate the user? set session authorization KYKE and then run a query against the schema and see if it succeeds.

Comment: yes...assuming they have access based on the query above. And yes, executing a revoke all and a revoke usage. When impersonating user...I can read the table.